# (Code-Completion) Combine two task lists (tables) in order to show the total results

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Today I'm trying to achieve something that I'm having difficulties with the code-completion.
I'm trying to combine two tasks (which  are from different types).

Before reaching here, I've tried several scenarios.... Using WhenAll to combine Tasks (which I cannot do this since both tasks are different).

The last part of the code (last 3 lines) are not correct and I'll ask if someone can take a look on this :) (Also if the method arguments are okay for this matter). All I want is to return the list of the total rows combined by the two tasks.

Thanks in advance! (Code is below)

```
public async Task<(ApplyPerfectMatches, ApplyNonPerfectMatches)>
                GetMatchesAsync(string currentUser)
            {
                // Perfect Matches
                var listPerfectMatches = _context.ApplyPerfectMatches
                    .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser)
                     // Use AsNoTracking to disable EF change tracking
                     // Use ToListAsync to avoid blocking a thread
                     .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    
                // Determine Total matches vs. Limit matches per user
                int totalMatches = _context.ApplyPerfectMatches.Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser).Count();
                int totalMatchesBy10 = totalMatches / 10;
    
                // n(n-1)/2 + 2 (n = 1...n+1 => 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 17, 23, 30...)
                int limitMatches = totalMatches < 10 ? 3 : (totalMatchesBy10 * (totalMatchesBy10 - 1) / 2) + 2;
    
                var submitDate = _context.ApplyPerfectMatches
                    .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DtSubmitInvestor)
                    .Select(x => x.DtSubmitInvestor)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    
                int days = (DateTime.Now - submitDate).Days;
    
                if (days > 3)
                {
                    listPerfectMatches = _context.ApplyPerfectMatches
                    .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser)
                    .Take(limitMatches)
                     // Use AsNoTracking to disable EF change tracking
                     // Use ToListAsync to avoid blocking a thread
                     .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    listPerfectMatches = _context.ApplyPerfectMatches
                    .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser)
                    .Take(3)
                     // Use AsNoTracking to disable EF change tracking
                     // Use ToListAsync to avoid blocking a thread
                     .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
                }            
    
                // Total Matches (Perfect + Non-Perfect Matches)
                var listNonPerfectMatches = _context.ApplyNonPerfectMatches
                    .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser)
                     // Use AsNoTracking to disable EF change tracking
                     // Use ToListAsync to avoid blocking a thread
                     .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    
    
                var finalResult = listPerfectMatches.Result.Concat(listNonPerfectMatches.Result).ToList();           
    
                //await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                //return tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Result).ToList();
            }
```

Update (I don't mind the negative votes but if someone needs help, that same person might be confused with the problem...):

```
result = await _context.ApplyTotalMatches
                // Only get entries for the current logged in user
                .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser && x.UnionSetOrder == 1)
                .Take(limitMatches)
                .Concat(_context.ApplyTotalMatches
                .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser && x.UnionSetOrder == 2))
                // Use AsNoTracking to disable EF change tracking
                // Use ToListAsync to avoid blocking a thread
                .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. You can't combine the results like you are trying, as the two lists are of different types. Are you trying to return a tuple wrapped in a task? Then you should try: "return Task.FromResult((listPerfectMatches, listNonPerfectMatches));" 
But, before you can do that, you need to await your ToListAsync() calls...

Comment: @GorgiRankovski sorry about that. I want the results from both lists. I've did what you suggested but I'm having an error on the return line.I think it's the method arguments --> public async Task<(ApplyPerfectMatches, ApplyNonPerfectMatches)>
            GetMatchesAsync(string currentUser)

Comment: Sorry, the correct code would be: "return (ApplyPerfectMatches, ApplyNonPerfectMatches);". 
Make sure to await all your ToListAsync lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `await` a `Task` object. This "unwraps" the result:

```
public async (List<ApplyPerfectMatches> PerfectMatches, List<ApplyNonPerfectMatches> NonApplyPerfectMatches) GetMatchesAsync(string currentUser)
{
  List<ApplyPerfectMatches> listPerfectMatches = await _context.ApplyPerfectMatches
    .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser)
    .Take(3)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();

  List<ApplyNonPerfectMatches> listNonPerfectMatches = await _context.ApplyNonPerfectMatches
    .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();

  return (listPerfectMatches, listNonPerfectMatches);   
}

async Task Run()
{
  (List<ApplyPerfectMatches> PerfectMatches, List<ApplyNonPerfectMatches> NonApplyPerfectMatches) result = await GetMatchesAsync("Admin");
}
```

Directly accessing `Task.Result` can cause a deadlock. `QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync` is an asynchronous method. Asynchronous methods always return a `Task<T>` or `Task` and must be awaited using `await` in order to execute asynchronously.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I'm having trouble on the return since I have to specify the objects when you declared the lists. I need to specify the object for both lists and they are from different outputs

Comment: What do you mean? It is a list of  `object`. You can replace `object` with the real type of course. I don't know the real type.

Comment: Both Lists have different types and that's why I get an error on the return line.
Sorry If I'm not clear, I hate when I'm like this

Comment: If both lists have different types you can't concatenate them. You'd have to return them separately (now I know what the tuple in return type signature was for). I will update the example.

Comment: Whatt are the actual types in the collections?

Comment: List<ApplyPerfectMatches> listPerfectMatches and
List<ApplyNonPerfectMatches> listNonPerfectMatches

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just worried how I'm going to union these results after retrieving this

Comment: To answer this I need more info about those two types. Are you interested in a particular property that is defined on both types?

Comment: Let me see if I can explain this clearly. Each type has a specific context (table from the database). I want to combine both results with a union

Comment: maybe I need to use LINQ to combine the results before returning the result. I'm a little confused on what to do lol

Comment: Ahh. Then you have to combine it when you query the database. You can't simply merge two collections of different types or types that don't belong to the same inheritance tree. If both types have a `IdEmailinvestor` property and you are only interested to return this value it is possible to unwrap the common property values using a `Enumerable.Select`. If both types have the same properties but only named different you can define an interface that is implemented by both types. Then you could merge both collections too.

Comment: Yes they have the same structure in the database. They represent two views that are each type that you've seen in the example.

Can you explain how can I achieve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: I've used my messy head and managed to accomplished everything in 1 view with an additional field that will make perfect and non-perfect matches noticed.

Comment: Will consider your answer correct since it was more clear to my confused mind

Comment: Good, you found a solution by yourself. Otherwise you could've wrapped both types into new type e.g. `MatchResult`. So your method would return a collection of  `IEnumerable<Matchresult>`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define a new class:

```
public class GetMatchesResult {
   public string IdEmailInvestor { set; get; }
   public bool IsPerfectMatch { set; get; }
   ... rest of properties/columns go here
}
```

Since your method is defined as

```
async Task<(ApplyPerfectMatches, ApplyNonPerfectMatches)>
```

you need to change it to:

```
async Task<List<GetMatchesResult>> GetMatches
```

Now, you need to update the queries to:

```
 // Perfect Matches
 var listPerfectMatches = await _context.ApplyPerfectMatches
     .Where(x => x.IdEmailInvestor == currentUser)
     .Select(x => new GetMatchesResult {
         IdEmailInvestor = x.IdEmailInvestor,
         IsPerfectMatch = true,
         ... rest of properties go here
     })
     // Use ToListAsync to avoid blocking a thread
     .ToListAsync();
```

You need to do the same with the listNonPerfectMatches, but set the IsPerfectMatch to false.

In the end, you can do:

```
return listPerfectMatches.Concat(listNonPerfectMatches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, my objective is to return the list of the total results combine from the two lists

Comment: Do you need to return two separate lists? Then see my updated answer @SergioVitalRebelo

Comment: I would like to return a list that is the combination of both. But it seems I cannot combine two different types. All of this to union two different outputs from the same view lol. Damn I need to think...

Comment: @SergioVitalRebelo the question is how are you going to use the results on the other side? You probably need to create a new class that will hold the desired properties and a boolean property IsPerfectMatch. Then, you need to map results from both lists into the same type AND THEN you can merge the two mapped lists into one and return the result.

Comment: They represent two views with the same properties (structure). I want to combine the results of each view.

Comment: Okay @SergioVitalRebelo see the answer now. I hope you can extrapolate the correct implementation for your use case.

Comment: I've used my messy head and managed to accomplished everything in 1 view with an additional field that will make perfect and non-perfect matches noticed.